# Find my phone issue

Tags: iphone

I think it is crazy on this option to send an email everytime.  This feature was added so if you lost your phone it could be found but it is also a good tool to check on your children or (spouse).  I do not like that it sends my child an email everytime I check it.  That should be parental control.  Makes you want to get an android that doesn't notify the person their phone was checked up on.

Comment: It's for finding the phone and not for tracking it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Find My iPhone helps you locate and protect your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, or Mac if it’s ever lost or stolen. It wasn't designed to keep tabs on a person's location.

More information about Find My iPhone can be found here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2696

Perhaps you should look for another tool that better suits your needs.